# How to replace outline with border by navigating through form using keyboard?

Tags: html, css

When you have a website and a form, you can navigate through the form using your keyboard tab-key. For example Google Chrome will provide the selected item with a blue outline.

**HTML**

```
<form method="" action="">
  <input type="text" tabindex="1">
  <input type="text" tabindex="2">
  <input type="submit" tabindex="3">
</form>
```

**CSS**

```
input:focus {
  outline: none;
  border: 1px solid blue;
}
```

See [FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/c3ygkz9j/).

This is working fine but I **only** want it applied when the user use the keyboard to navigate. When normal focussed on the input I want the border to disappear.

So what I want in CSS is the following (not working):

```
input:navigatedbytabkey { ... }
```

Do anyone know a good solution?

Comment: I dont think this is possible with pure CSS o.O

Comment: You can't. A keyboard focus _is_ a "normal" focus

Comment: Okay... But it is possible in JS?

Comment: @djl It seems to be tricky. Consider using keypress listeners on your form, and then anticipating where the user focus will be changed. So for instance, if the focus is on the first field, and they press tab, you will have a listener for this event which will remove the border on the next field.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this with pure CSS, still yo can do it with javascript/Jquery.

What you could do is hold an event listener for tab key press, and on that event check what element gets focus, and if it is inside your form, hightlight it. I find it better to hightlight it using a class instead of applying css directly.

I will use JQuery because it just saves a lot of valuable time.

CSS:

```
.tab-focused{
    //HERE COMES YOUR ON-TAB-FOCUS STYLING
}
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(window).keyup(function(e){//this listens for any key being presssed
        if(e.keyCode==9){//this checks that the key pressed is tab
            var focusedElement = $(':focus');
            if (focusedElement.parents('form').length){//check if the focused element is inside the form
                focusedElement.addClass('tab-focused');
                //This still has one problem. When you get out of an element, it's class is not being removed. So, let's add another event to detect whenever they lose focus(blur)
                focusedElement.one('blur',function(){
                    $(this).removeClass('tab-focused');
                });
            }
        }
    }
});
```

I have not tested this, but it should work, or at least, it is a start for you to develop what you want. If you can't manage to make it work, don't be afraid of asking for further help.

Good luck!